# Who is the murderer in P'tit Quinquin or Li'l Quinquin?

Tags: plot-explanation, ptit-quinquin

Who is the real killer in Bruno Dumont's *P'tit Quinquin*? Is it the biker, Quinquin's uncle or someone else?

Comment: Is your question about p'tit quinquin or li'l quinquin? One is a movie and other is a TV series.

Comment: Meta question about how this question's tag should be written: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/how-should-titles-like-ptit-quinquin-be-tagged